# Reading ORC file in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, orc

I'm reading ORC files from local directory from pyspark using Structured Streaming

```
    StructField("RowNo", StringType()),
    StructField("InvoiceNo", StringType()),
    StructField("StockCode", StringType()),
    StructField("Description", StringType()),
    StructField("Quantity", StringType()),
    StructField("InvoiceDate", StringType()),
    StructField("UnitPrice", StringType()),
    StructField("CustomerId", StringType()),
    StructField("Country", StringType()),
    StructField("InvoiceTimestamp", StringType())
])

data = spark.readStream.format("orc").schema(schema).option("header", "true").option("path",r"\retail-data-orc").load()
```

But when I show data on console using this code

```
query = data.writeStream.format(source="console").outputMode("update").start()
```

I'm getting NULL values only. I don't know the reason

Comment: try to read it without streaming, and compare your schema with detected schema

Comment: seems like your schema is not matched with actual data, read data withoud stream take that schema as json & use that json schema for streaming.

Comment: when I read without streaming, then it generates no problem. But when I read it in streaming it shows only null values